# How can I get Xcode working on my Mac Sierra (10.12.6)

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

I seem to have gotten stuck in MacOS / Xcode purgatory.

I'm on OS Sierra/10.12.6.

When I try to update, I get a warning, that there's an issue with upgrading vs DisplayLink and so it cannot be done.

That directly conflicts with Xcode which (as of now, on App Store) only works on 10.13.2 or later.

I cannot find a place to download an earlier version of Xcode.
I cannot upgrade to High Sierra.

How can I get this happening?

Comment: i'm running Xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Be warned by this comment: Version 9.4.1 needs 10.13.2 or later! I lost 1 hour downloading and unpacking... Have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can get it here at this URL: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ to download a version of Xcode you want. Specifically, get 9.2. This is the recent version that works with mac OS Sierra.

Edit: Xcode 9.2.1 is no longer an available version. 9.2 works.

Comment: You sir are a god damn legend. @alrodi

Comment: I can't find a 9.2.1 release, but Xcode 9.2 seems to be good. I also discovered this handy resource: https://xcodereleases.com/

Comment: I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 and downloaded the xCode version 10.2.1 and it's can't using now . Can anyone recommend for me a version of Xcode comfortable with this version of Mac os? Thanks

Comment: If you only need the Command Line tools, there are two releases for versione 9.2. Make sure to download the one for Mac OS 10.12.

Comment: 9.2 did not work for me, it required 10.12.6, I have 10.12, Sierra

Comment: @HammadKhan why not upgrade to 10.12.6?

Comment: @Locness I was using older macbook pro at the time, could not upgrade to the latest. Was not supported.

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 9.2 works well for Mac OS Sierra (10.12.6). I installed it today (3rd Feb 2020).

Answer (score 0):

For OS Sierra/10.12.6 you need Xcode-8.3 from below link

https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3/Xcode_8.3.xip

The Xcode-9* versions are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode 9.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip) is working fine on High Sierra. I have downloaded and installed it today.